Ошибка при установкe библиотеки aiogram
Я пытался установить aiogram на python 3.12.7-1 с помощью команды pip install aiogram , но появляется эта ошибка:
~/Hikka $ pip install aiogram
Collecting aiogram
  Using cached aiogram-3.14.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
Collecting aiofiles<24.2,>=23.2.1 (from aiogram)
  Using cached aiofiles-24.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<3.11,>=3.9.0 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from aiogram) (3.10.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2023.7.22 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from aiogram) (2024.8.30)
Collecting magic-filter<1.1,>=1.0.12 (from aiogram)
  Using cached magic_filter-1.0.12-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
Collecting pydantic<2.10,>=2.4.1 (from aiogram)
  Using cached pydantic-2.9.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (149 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions<=5.0,>=4.7.0 (from aiogram)
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohappyeyeballs>=2.3.0 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.11,>=3.9.0->aiogram) (2.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: aiosignal>=1.1.2 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.11,>=3.9.0->aiogram) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.11,>=3.9.0->aiogram) (24.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: frozenlist>=1.1.1 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.11,>=3.9.0->aiogram) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.11,>=3.9.0->aiogram) (6.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.12.0 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.11,>=3.9.0->aiogram) (1.17.1)
Collecting annotated-types>=0.6.0 (from pydantic<2.10,>=2.4.1->aiogram)
  Using cached annotated_types-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
Collecting pydantic-core==2.23.4 (from pydantic<2.10,>=2.4.1->aiogram)
  Using cached pydantic_core-2.23.4.tar.gz (402 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [68 lines of output]
      Collecting maturin<2,>=1
        Using cached maturin-1.7.4.tar.gz (191 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting typing-extensions!=4.7.0,>=4.6.0
        Using cached typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
      Using cached typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: maturin
        Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        × Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [43 lines of output]
            /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py:251: _IncompatibleBdistWheel: wheel.bdist_wheel is deprecated, please import it from setuptools
            !!

                    ********************************************************************************
                    Ensure that any custom bdist_wheel implementation is a subclass of
                    setuptools.command.bdist_wheel.bdist_wheel.

                    By 2025-Oct-15, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
                    or your builds will no longer be supported.

                    See https://github.com/pypa/wheel/pull/631 for details.
                    ********************************************************************************

            !!
              return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
            running bdist_wheel
            running build
            running build_py
            creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/maturin
            copying maturin/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/maturin
            copying maturin/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-312/maturin
            running egg_info
            writing maturin.egg-info/PKG-INFO
            writing dependency_links to maturin.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
            writing requirements to maturin.egg-info/requires.txt
            writing top-level names to maturin.egg-info/top_level.txt
            reading manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
            warning: no files found matching '*.json' under directory 'src/python_interpreter'
            writing manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            running build_ext
            running build_rust
            error: can't find Rust compiler

            If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

            To update pip, run:

                pip install --upgrade pip

            and then retry package installation.

            If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin
      Failed to build maturin
      ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (maturin)
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Для начала попробуйте pip install --upgrade setuptools

А ещё из интересного там: error: can't find Rust compiler Попробуйте поставить компилятор Rust.

@CrazyElf при установке компилятора появились ошибки: Using cached matplotlib-3.9.2.tar.gz (36.1 MB)   Installing build dependencies ... error Installing backend dependencies: still running...         Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'error' Building wheel for patchelf (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error' и ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (patchelf, ninja)

@CrazyElf библиотека setuptools установлена

@anata Та строчка её обновляет. Некоторым на английском СО это помогло. Но в целом самому зависимости питона регулировать - это ад. Лучше какую-то готовую экосистему взять, ту же conda в каком-то из вариантов, например.

@CrazyElf я попробовал ее, но ничего не произошло
